# How can I assign a value to a cell by referencing a seperate table in Excel/Mac Numbers?

Tags: excel-formula

Table 2

| Pts | # of tix sold |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 300 |
| 3 | 400 |
| 4 | 500 |
| 5 | 600 |

Example: In Table 1 Tim sold 198 tickets. He didn't make it to 200 tickets sold, so he gets 0 pts. Bill sold 220, so he gets 1 pt. The points show in the cell next to the name on Table 1, but references table 2.

I tried using xlookup and index, but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XLOOKUP provides several matching modes, and one is "exact match or next smallest" which is what you want.  If the lookup value is 225, I want it to start down the list, and if it finds 225, it selects that row;  if it encounters any number > 225 then it knows it's gone too far and selects the previous number.  This sounds like the logic you want.

Assume:

- Tim's ticket count is in B2, and you want his points in C2;
- The lookup table is on a second worksheet, titled "Table2";
- The lookup table headers are A1:B1, and the data is the 6 rows below that;
- The lookup table should be in ascending ticket count order.

Then, in table1 cell C2 place this:

`=XLOOKUP(A2, table2!$B$2:$B$7, table2!$A$2:$A$7, "", -1)`

And copy it down the rows of column C.

The `-1` argument tells lookup "exact match or next smallest".

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. No table headers, just had to change it to this: XLOOKUP(A2, Table 2::$B$1:$B$6,Table 2::$A$1:$A$6,0,1)